# Как сэмулировать действие spin buttons?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Здравствуйте!

Имеем примерно такой input:

```
<input  type="number"
    id="{{ variable.opt.name }}"
    name = "{{ variable.opt.name }}"
    min  = "{{ variable.opt.min }}"
    max  = "{{ variable.opt.max }}"
    step = "{{ variable.opt.step }}"
    ng-model = "variable.opt.value">
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно сэмулировать действие "стрелочек вверх/вниз" у тега `input[type="number"]`

**Мои действия:**

Скрыл их с помощью CSS:

```
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
input[type='number'] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}
```

Далее с помощью jQuery:

1. Подставляю свои стрелочки

```
setTimeout(function () {
    angular.element('input[type="number"]').each(function () {
        var t = jQuery(this);

        t.wrap('<div class="sb"></div>');
        t.before('<div class="sb-arrow sb-up"><i class="fl-up-arrow"></i></div>').after('<div class="sb-arrow sb-down"><i class="fl-down-arrow-2"></i></div>');
    });
}, 100);
```

2. Произвожу такие манипуляции (Ловлю нажатие на стрелочку и просто заменяю значение):

```
angular.element('body').on('click', '.sb-arrow', function () {
    var t = jQuery(this),
        input = t.parent().children('input'),
        step = (input.attr('step')) ? Number(input.attr('step')) : 1;

    if (t.hasClass('sb-up')) {
        input.val(Number(input.val()) + step);
        console.log('click');
    } else if (t.hasClass('sb-down')) {
        input.val(Number(input.val()) - step);
    }
});
```

И вроде бы как всё работает: циферки меняются.

**НО!** Изменения в модели не происходит :(

Попробовал так:

```
angular.element('body').on('click', '.sb-arrow', function () {
    var t = jQuery(this),
        input = t.parent().children('input'),
        step = (input.attr('step')) ? Number(input.attr('step')) : 1;

    if (t.hasClass('sb-up')) {
        var e = new jQuery.Event("keyup", { keyCode: 38 } );
        input.trigger(e)
    } else if (t.hasClass('sb-down')) {
        input.val(Number(input.val()) - step);
    }
});
```

Так вообще ничего не происходит.

Comment: так а зачем jquery???

Comment: @Grundy, а есть другой вариант? )

Comment: конечно, пишешь свою директиву средствами ангуляра - и все ок

Comment: @Grundy, Спасибо, щас буду думать/пробовать )

Comment: @Grundy, я извиняюсь, но что бы не создавать лишний вопрос: подскажите, можно ли передать в директиву модель?)

Comment: передать в директиву модель можно.

Comment: @Grundy, а как это сделать? И как "прочитать" её в директиве?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вся проблема в данном случае заключается в том, что при изменении значения поля ввода напрямую, ангуляр не знает, что что-то произошло и не обновляет значения соответствующих переменных.

Вместо использования jQuery, стоит написать свою директиву.

Задать ей сразу нужный шаблон, и передать в качестве параметра объект с настройками.

Директива может выглядеть так:

```
.directive('myInput',function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope:{
      options: '=' // указываем название параметра
    },
    template: `
    <div class="sb">
      <div class="sb-arrow sb-up" ng-click="up()">
        <i class="fl-up-arrow">^</i>
      </div>

      <input  type="number"
        id="{{ options.name }}"
        name = "{{ options.name }}"
        min  = "{{ options.min }}"
        max  = "{{ options.max }}"
        step = "{{ options.step }}"
        ng-model = "options.value">

      <div class="sb-arrow sb-down" ng-click="down()">
        <i class="fl-down-arrow-2">v</i>
      </div>
    </div>`,
    link: function(scope){
      // методы обработчики нажатия на кнопки. В них стоит добавить дополнительную логику проверки границ.
      scope.up = function(){ 
        scope.options.value += scope.options.step;
      };
      scope.down = function(){
        scope.options.value -= scope.options.step;
      }
    }
  };
});
```

Пример использования данной директивы:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.variable = {
      opt: {
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        step: 10,
        value: 40,
        name: 'sample'
      }
    };
  })
  .directive('myInput', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        options: '=' // указываем название параметра
      },
      template: `
        <div class="sb">
          <div class="sb-arrow sb-up" ng-click="up()">
            <i class="fl-up-arrow">^</i>
          </div>

          <input  type="number"
            id="{{ options.name }}"
            name = "{{ options.name }}"
            min  = "{{ options.min }}"
            max  = "{{ options.max }}"
            step = "{{ options.step }}"
            ng-model = "options.value">

          <div class="sb-arrow sb-down" ng-click="down()">
            <i class="fl-down-arrow-2">v</i>
          </div>
        </div>`,
      link: function(scope) {
        // методы обработчики нажатия на кнопки. В них стоит добавить дополнительную логику проверки границ.
        scope.up = function() {
          scope.options.value += scope.options.step;
        };
        scope.down = function() {
          scope.options.value -= scope.options.step;
        }
      }
    };
  });
```

```html
<script data-require="angular.js@1.6.2" data-semver="1.6.2" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <my-input options="variable.opt"></my-input>
  <pre>
{{variable|json}}
  </pre>
</div>
```